# registration issue with iMacros

Tags: imacros

Hi I have a problem in the recording of `iMacros`, my problem is that at some point in the recording when my portal you open a form in `HTML5` lines of code are automatically commented `Imacros` and consequently when I finish recording and reproduce it gives me own error in that line.
I post my code `iMacros`, someone knows how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Were you trying to include some code with this question?

Comment: this is my code imacros:

Comment: ATTR=NAME:submit
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:CASINO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:TODOS
TAG POS=18 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:JUGAR
'TAG POS=0 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=ID:defaultTime
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=ID:defaultAmount
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=TXT:GUARDAR<SP>CAMBIOS
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=TXT:GUARDAR<SP>CAMBIOS

Comment: 'TAG POS=0 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=ID:defaultTime
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:sessLts ATTR=ID:defaultAmount
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=YES